# straightforward calculus problem

Tags: calculus, problem-solving

Find the arc length of the graph of $\displaystyle \large x^{\frac{2}{3}}+y^{\frac{2}{3}}=1$.

**Hint**: Use symmetry with respect to the line $y=x$.

Let $y=x$ intersect at $a$. So, $\displaystyle a=\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{\large \frac{3}{2}}.$

Then $\displaystyle y'=-\frac{\sqrt{1-x^{\large\frac{2}{3}}}}{x^{\large \frac{1}{3}}}$

The arc length is $$\displaystyle \sqrt{1+\frac{\left(1-x^{\large \frac{2}{3}}\right)}{\left(x^{\large \frac{1}{3}}\right)^2}}=x^{-\large \frac{1}{3}}$$

Now, I don't know how to finish. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

**Suggestion:** For the first quadrant part of the curve, use the parametrization $x=\cos^3\theta$, $y=\sin^3\theta$. Then we want to integrate
$$\sqrt{\left(\frac{dx}{d\theta}\right)^2+  \left(\frac{dy}{d\theta}\right)^2},$$
which simplifies very nicely.

**Added:** For the full arclength using your approach, integrate $x^{-1/3}$ from $0$ to $1$, and multiply by $4$ to take care of the pieces of the curve that lie in the other quadrants. By the symmetry of the curve, these all have the same length as the first quadrant part.

If you want, you can exploit the symmetry between $x$ and $y$ and find the arclength of the first quadrant part by integrating from $0$ to $a$, and multiplying the result by $2$. Then multiply by $4$ to get the full arclength.

Comment: Wait does this answer follow? The answer I am looking for is 8*(integral(x^(-1/3)) from a to 1).

Comment: With the trig approach, we get $4$ times the integral from $0$ to $\pi/2$ of $3\cos\theta\sin\theta$. Note that $\cos\thta\sin\theta$ is the derivative of $(1/2)\sin^2\theta$. I really don't think that the extra symmetry that gets us $8$ times the integral of $x^{-1/3}$ speeds up the computation.

Comment: How does it get 8 times?

Comment: There are $4$ pieces of identical length, one in each quadrant, because our curve does not care about the sign of $x$ and $y$. The first quadrant part, by the symmetry between $x$ and $y$, is divided into two pieces of the same length at $a$.  The $8$ is $(4)(2)$.